# Is it possible to re-create certificate that was created with EFS?

Tags: windows-7, disk-encryption, efs

I have some files that are encrypted with EFS. I do not have the certificate to decrypt. But I do know the username, computer name, password, etc. that were used when the files were created. Is there a way to recover the files?

- If yes, how?
- If not, what other information does windows use to create the certificate.

**EDIT** (some additional information after the first few answers): So, I have a corrupted windows hard drive that doesn't boot anymore. But I can access essentially all files when I connect it as an external hard drive. So, my thinking is, that if I can extract the certificate (which is protected by the user-password [?] that i know) from the registry. I could maybe access the corresponding files ...

Comment: Without the certificate the files cannot be decrypted.  You cannot just simply "recreate" the certificate.  There is no work around to your problem if you don't have a copy of the original certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate a certificate, but only if you have the private key that it used. If you are going to do certificate-based disk encryption, you need to have a secure backup for your certificate and/or keys.